# AWS Server Size for Hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking into purchasing server space with AWS to host what will eventually be over 50 websites. They will have many different ranges of traffic coming in. I would like to know if anyone has a recommendation on what size of server that would be able to handle this many sites.

Also, I was wondering if it's more cost effective/efficient to host an separate EC-2 instance for each site or too purchase a large umbrella server and host all sites on a single instance?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Co-locating services** on single/multiple servers is a core architecting decision your firm should make. It will directly impact the performance, security and cost of your systems.

The benefit of having multiple services on the same Amazon EC2 instance is that they can **share resources** (RAM, CPU) so if one application is busy, it has access to more total resources. This is in contrast to running each one on a separate instance, where there is a smaller, finite quantity of resources. Think of it like car-pooling vs riding motorbikes.

Sharing resources means you can probably **lower costs**, since you'll need less total capacity.

From a **security perspective**, running on separate instances is much better because they are isolated from each other. You should also investigate network isolation to prevent potential breaches between instances on the same virtual network.

You should also look at the ability to host all of these services using a **multi-tenant system** as opposed to 50 completely separate systems. This has further benefits in terms of sharing resources and reducing costs. For example, Salesforce.com doesn't run a separate computer for each customer -- all the customers use the same systems, but security and data is kept separate at the application layer.

**Bottom line:** There are some major architectural decisions to make if you wish to roll-out secure, performant systems.

Answer (score 1):

The short correct answer:

If those sites are only static(html, css and js). EC2 won't be necessary because you can use S3 and it will be more cheap and you won't have to worry about scaling.

But if those sites have a dynamic part like php, python and similar. Well it is a different story.